# some questions about homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Describe the image and kernel of each of the homomorphisms given below.

1. $f : [\mathbb{Z}]_{12} → [\mathbb{Z}]_4$, where $f([a]_{12}) = [a]_4$. In addition to describing the image and kernel of $f$, prove that $f$ is well-defined.
2. $g : R × S → R$, where $g(r, s) = r$. (Here, $R$ and $S$ are arbitrary rings.)
3. $h : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, where $h(a + bi) = a − bi$.

From (1),I know that it let us to prove if $[a]_{12} = [b]_{12}$, then $f([a]_{12}) = f([b]_{12})$. But I don't have any strategies to do the following steps.

Could someone to help me to do these 3 questions?I'd appreciate it.

Comment: tried to faithfully represent your intent, please check the edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some hints to get you started.

1. You want to show that $[a]_4 = [b]_4$ given that $[a]_{12} = [b]_{12}$. By definition, if $[a]_{12} = [b]_{12}$, then $a = b + 12k$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$. To show that $[a]_4 = [b]_4$, you need to show that $a = b + 4k'$ for some $k'\in\Bbb Z$. To determine the image and kernel in this case, you can simply compute $f(x)$ for each $x\in\Bbb Z/(12)$ (there are only $12$ elements to compute), and check which elements map to $0$ and which elements of $\Bbb Z/(4)$ occur as $f(x)$ for some $x$.
2. $$
   \ker(g) = \{(r,s)\in R\times S\mid g(r,s) = 0\}.
   $$
   Which pairs $(r,s)\in R\times S$ have this property? To compute the image, take $r\in R$, and see if you can find $(\tilde{r},\tilde{s})\in R\times S$ such that $g(\tilde{r},\tilde{s}) = r$. Write out what $g(r,s)$ is and you should be able to finish it up.
3. To find the kernel, check when $a - bi = 0$. If $a - bi = 0$, then $a + bi\in\ker h$. To find the image, start with $c + di\in\Bbb C$. When is there a pair $a + bi\in\Bbb C$ such that $h(a + bi) = a - bi = c + di$?